Axios Error and errors with postrgresql on django deployment
simple django/react app just start learning how to deploy with railway.
current error is "Unsupported protocol postgresql:"
so tried adding "http://" and "https://" to the api url, which gave cors error and still wasn't working, so reverted back to code below.
import axios from "axios";
import { ACCESS_TOKEN } from "./constants";

const apiUrl =
  //protocol missing?
  "postgresql://postgres:ttNgMy**@monorail.proxy.rlwy.net:50695/railway";

const api = axios.create({
  //import anything stored in an enviroment variable
  baseURL: apiUrl ? apiUrl : import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,

  //local http://127.0.0.01 = import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL
});

errors:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: y.response is undefined
message: "Unsupported protocol postgresql:"
name: "AxiosError"

The error message is clear: postgresql is not a scheme supported by Axios.

ahh ok I’ll try replacing that

It looks like you're trying to call your PostgreSQL database like an API, which doesn't work - first, you'll need to make an API around it. I'm not that familiar with Django, but if you're new to Django, you're going to want to skim this part of the Django tutorial which deals with databases. Essentially, you're going to want to connect to your database from your backend using a dedicated PostgreSQL client (not an HTTP client, which is what Axios is); Django provides an ORM (object-relational mapping) that makes database access much easier than using raw SQL. Then, you can make a few endpoints under /api or a similar path that manipulate your data that you can then call using Axios (or another solution, like the Fetch API, or TanStack Query, both of which I would recommend over Axios for a modern app, and especially the latter for React) from your frontend.
In theory, you could use some PostgreSQL clients from your frontend, but that's not secure - if you have your frontend connecting directly, then not only are your database credentials sent to the frontend in clear text, but there's also no opportunity for you to add secure authorization logic. You can, of course, add some if statements in your frontend, but there's nothing to stop a bad actor from taking your connection string and bypassing that by going directly to the database. There are some options that allow you to manage data securely directly from a frontend app without writing a backend yourself, like Firebase and Supabase, but connecting to a regular database like PostgreSQL from a frontend is generally a bad idea, and you already have a perfectly good backend in Django.

oh ok wow, I do have an API for it but didn't even realize I was trying to use the db directly that makes sense now, and yeah axios has been a headache I'm gonna try a different route. 1st time so lots of newbie stuff happening here lol but thanks a ton for the help
